# Django form: ModelChoiceField(multiple-select) similar to ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal?

Tags: python, django, forms

How can I create a field ModelChoiceField(multiple-select) in my own form, similar to that available on admin site (ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal)?

- Two boxes side by side
- Interface that allows searching

Follow the image below:

[ChoiceField-MultipleSelect "Admin"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WljX.png)

Comment: https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2010/05/14/reuse-djangos-filter_horizontal-admin-widget.html

Comment: @GrandPhuba thank you!